# Different css for mobile devices not just based on media query

Tags: android, jquery, css

Now a days mobile devices are coming in HD screen resolution, writing the css just based on @media query not seems to be enough. I know this question has been asked previously ... still just want to know the different ways of writing (effectively) same web page for desktop and handheld devices.

Even "Stackoverflow" looks differently when we minimized the browser width and in mobile.If some one has  "jsfiddle" or some other css/jquery example please share

Comment: If you want to ask question that was asked before you need to clearly explain what is not answered in previous one. So far looks like duplicate.

Comment: If possible how this site(stackoverflow.com) is working..? Are they maintaining different sites for mobile and PC or just through CSS..? Please let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

If HD screens are your concern, then @media queries still have you covered:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { ... }
```

Also see this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/